# How to count the number of consecutive days a value grows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following df:

```
Date
2015-11-27    105.449997
2015-11-30    104.239998
2015-12-01    107.120003
2015-12-02    106.070000
2015-12-03    104.379997
                 ...    
2020-11-18    271.970001
2020-11-19    272.940002
2020-11-20    269.700012
2020-11-23    268.429993
2020-11-24    276.920013
Name: Close, Length: 1258, dtype: float64
```

What I am trying to do is find for how many days in a row has the `Close` closed lower than the previous day. Could you please advise how I can go about this?

For example:
[image]

At this point it would say `Close` was lower for the last 3 days on `Date`

```
    Date          Close     Days
    10/30/2020  263.109985  0.0
    11/2/2020   261.359985  1.0
    11/3/2020   265.299988  0.0
    11/4/2020   287.380005  1.0
    11/5/2020   294.679993  0.0
    11/6/2020   293.410004  1.0
    11/9/2020   278.769989  0.0
    11/10/2020  272.429993  1.0
    11/11/2020  276.480011  0.0
    11/12/2020  275.079987  1.0
    11/13/2020  276.950012  0.0
    11/16/2020  278.959991  0.0
    11/17/2020  275.000000  1.0
    11/18/2020  271.970001  2.0
    11/19/2020  272.940002  0.0
    11/20/2020  278.000000  1.0
    11/23/2020  277.000000  2.0
    11/24/2020  276.920013  3.0
```

How can achieve this?

Comment: what is expected output fom sample?

Comment: A number which would check the most recent value previous values(s) and output should be number of days:

Comment: What is previous day? Is `2020-11-20` previous day for `2020-11-23`, because misisng `21, 22` (weekend) ?

Comment: yes there are missing dates in the data, that is avoidable. Just whenever was the previous day.

Comment: I try understand and failed, why is count day for `11/18/2020`, if `271.970001 < 272.940002` ? Why is not count `11/16/2020` but `278.959991 > 275.000000` ?

Answer (score 5):

Use the following code:

```
# Is the current "Close" increasing or same (compared with previous row)
df['incr'] = df.Close >= df.Close.shift(fill_value=0)
# Generate the result column
df['DaysDecr'] = df.groupby(df.incr.cumsum()).apply(
    lambda grp: (~grp.incr).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
# Drop "incr" column
df.drop(columns='incr', inplace=True)
```

For your data sample the result is:

```
         Date       Close  Days  DaysDecr
0  2020-10-30  263.109985   0.0         0
1  2020-11-02  261.359985   1.0         1
2  2020-11-03  265.299988   0.0         0
3  2020-11-04  287.380005   1.0         0
4  2020-11-05  294.679993   0.0         0
5  2020-11-06  293.410004   1.0         1
6  2020-11-09  278.769989   0.0         2
7  2020-11-10  272.429993   1.0         3
8  2020-11-11  276.480011   0.0         0
9  2020-11-12  275.079987   1.0         1
10 2020-11-13  276.950012   0.0         0
11 2020-11-16  278.959991   0.0         0
12 2020-11-17  275.000000   1.0         1
13 2020-11-18  271.970001   2.0         2
14 2020-11-19  272.940002   0.0         0
15 2020-11-20  278.000000   1.0         0
16 2020-11-23  277.000000   2.0         1
17 2020-11-24  276.920013   3.0         2
```

To trace how this code works, generate the grouping:

```
df['incr'] = df.Close >= df.Close.shift(fill_value=0)
gr = df.groupby(df.incr.cumsum())
```

and print each group:

```
for key, grp in gr:
    print(f'\nGroup: {key}\n{grp}')
```

Note that *incr* column in each group starts with a single *True* (the
date when *Close* either increased or stayed the same) and then there is
a sequence of *False* (days when *Close* was lower that on the previous
date).

So the result can be generated by negation of *incr* and *cumsum()* of it.

And the only thing to do is to drop *incr* column (not needed any more).

Comment: Thanks Valdi_Bo for the answer. This should work well

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple quick and dirty solution for your problem. I put your sample data in a csv file and imported it using `pandas`. The rest should be described in the comments of the code:

```
    import pandas as pd
    #import your data from a csv that contains two columns with the headers "Date" and "Close"
    df = pd.read_csv("/your_path/sample_data.txt")
    
    #choose the column "Close" and save it into the variable "close"
    close = df["Close"]
    
    #go through dataframe and count the days where they increase
    counter = 0
    for i in range(1, len(close)):
        if close[i] > close[i-1]:
            counter = counter + 1
        else:
            counter = 0
    
    #print the amount of days that the closes increased
    print("The closes have increased over the last " + str(counter) + " days")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution by using the function `apply` to calculate this value for a given row.

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ["Date", "Close", "Days"]
data = [
    ["10/30/2020", 263.109985, 0.0],
    ["11/02/2020", 261.359985, 1.0],
    ["11/03/2020", 265.299988, 0.0],
    ["11/04/2020", 287.380005, 1.0],
    ["11/05/2020", 294.679993, 0.0],
    ["11/06/2020", 293.410004, 1.0],
    ["11/09/2020", 278.769989, 0.0],
    ["11/10/2020", 272.429993, 1.0],
    ["11/11/2020", 276.480011, 0.0],
    ["11/12/2020", 275.079987, 1.0],
    ["11/13/2020", 276.950012, 0.0],
    ["11/16/2020", 278.959991, 0.0],
    ["11/17/2020", 275.000000, 1.0],
    ["11/18/2020", 271.970001, 2.0],
    ["11/19/2020", 272.940002, 0.0],
    ["11/20/2020", 278.000000, 1.0],
    ["11/23/2020", 277.000000, 2.0],
    ["11/24/2020", 276.920013, 3.0]
]
# Load from data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
# Convert to datetime
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%m/%d/%Y")
# Order by date
df.sort_values(["Date"], ascending=True, inplace=True)

def find_last(df, my_date, my_close, count):
    previous_index = df[df["Date"]<my_date]["Date"].max()
    previous_close = df[df["Date"]==previous_index]["Close"].max()
    if df[df["Date"] < my_date]["Date"].count()>0 and my_close < previous_close:
        return find_last(df[df["Date"]<my_date], previous_index, previous_close, count + 1)
    else:
        return count

df["days_calc"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: find_last(df.copy(), row["Date"], row["Close"], 0), axis=1)
```

Output:

```py
    Date        Close       Days    days_calc
0   2020-10-30  263.109985  0.0     0
1   2020-11-02  261.359985  1.0     1
2   2020-11-03  265.299988  0.0     0
3   2020-11-04  287.380005  1.0     0
4   2020-11-05  294.679993  0.0     0
5   2020-11-06  293.410004  1.0     1
6   2020-11-09  278.769989  0.0     2
7   2020-11-10  272.429993  1.0     3
8   2020-11-11  276.480011  0.0     0
9   2020-11-12  275.079987  1.0     1
10  2020-11-13  276.950012  0.0     0
11  2020-11-16  278.959991  0.0     0
12  2020-11-17  275.000000  1.0     1
13  2020-11-18  271.970001  2.0     2
14  2020-11-19  272.940002  0.0     0
15  2020-11-20  278.000000  1.0     0
16  2020-11-23  277.000000  2.0     1
17  2020-11-24  276.920013  3.0     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made this and it should work for you.

```py
import pandas as pd

columns = ["Date", "Close"]
data = [
    ["10/30/2020", 263.109985],
    ["11/02/2020", 261.359985],
    ["11/03/2020", 265.299988],
    ["11/04/2020", 287.380005],
    ["11/05/2020", 294.679993],
    ["11/06/2020", 293.410004],
    ["11/09/2020", 278.769989],
    ["11/10/2020", 272.429993],
    ["11/11/2020", 276.480011],
    ["11/12/2020", 275.079987],
    ["11/13/2020", 276.950012],
    ["11/16/2020", 278.959991],
    ["11/17/2020", 275.000000],
    ["11/18/2020", 271.970001],
    ["11/19/2020", 272.940002],
    ["11/20/2020", 278.000000],
    ["11/23/2020", 277.000000],
    ["11/24/2020", 276.920013],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

NewList = []
counter = 0

for i in range(len(df["Close"])):
    print(i)
    if i == 0:
        NewList.append(0)
        continue
    previous = int(i)-1
    if df["Close"][i] > df["Close"][previous]:
             counter += 1
             NewList.append(counter)
    else:
             counter = 0
             NewList.append(counter)

df["Days"] = NewList
```