# Python Pandas Dataframe: How to append more than one index to a list at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop, slice

Rewritten with what I think is hopefully an easier question to understand.

What I think the problem is, is not being able to append more than one item to a list at a time.

> Imagine using df.iloc[3:6] , But instead it is:
> myList.append(Start:Finish)

## pseudocode

```
# looping through an index and adding something to it when true
for (x)each index in the index:
    if condition is true:
        myList.append(x)
```

## below code works, but it is inefficient

```
# looping through an index and adding something to it when true
for (x)each index in the index:
    if condition is true:
        myList.append(x),myList.append(x+1),myList.append(x+2)
```

## what I would like to be able to do

```
# looping through an index and adding something to it when true
for (x)each index in the index:
    if condition is true:
        myList.append(x -> x+2) #myList.append(x+1),myList.append(x+2)

# so I want: myList.append(x to x+1 to x+2) 
# but without having to keep writing x+this , x+that ...
```

## Instead of this

> myList.append(x), myList.append(x+1), myList.append(x_2) (etc)

## I want to be able to write the same as

> myList.append(THIS POSITION -> numbers inbetween AND -> FINAL POSITION)

If it is not clear enough I am sorry and I will write spaghetti code until I figure it out

Comment: can you share a sample input dataframe and an expected output dataframe.

Comment: I will edit my question adding an example

Comment: where is the dataframe?

Comment: I don't know if I can upload the file so I will create one now, bear with me please

Comment: `g = lambda x,y: range(x,x+y);g(7,4)` ??? can you use something like this. I didn't understant your question properly sorry

Comment: @Pygirl I added some more info to the question now. Thanks for the code, i've never really used lambda but I will try it out

Comment: @JoeFerndz And I am not looking to get a dataframe output with the above code, but I use the code above to get index positions into lists and then I use .index.isin(n_future)  to get the dataframe

Comment: What are you trying to sum like this? which variable?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal What the code does, and does fine, just inefficiently, is:
Get index positions of the dataframe rows where if conditions are true, and add those to a list, of which I can then search and see isolated, from using df.index.isin(lists)

Comment: @helloworldnoob, sadly your code is not reproducable which is why I asked the question. On running your code (copying your data as is using `df.read_clipboard('\s\s+')`), the 2 lists normal and n_future show as blank. Probably because of `df.query('a_column>0').index`, with the column only having 0 values in sample.

Comment: For someone to help you with your problem they would either need to know the detailed logic OR be able to replicate your results, both of which are not available. Do add that info if possible Thanks.

Comment: Also, I am not the downvoter but I am voting to close due to lack of clarity. Will retract the vote when you can update the question. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How should I change the question? The file I'm working with has over 4000 rows and many more columns. I thought the idea behind the question was fine to understand. EDIT: reading the link now, thank you

Comment: However, with the final part of my question labaled 'FURTHER EDIT:'

Do you understand what I mean and what I want to do?

Comment: A lot of people who join SO have the same problem. its not just you. Its difficult to frame a large problem into a smaller one, but its necessary for the sake of others who can help. I have provided a link for the same. You can create a dummy table with the same operation but 10 rows. write the expected output.

Comment: Check the first comment as well, its upvoted 4 times and asks for the same, and for good reason. You do have a good question, a complex one. but its up to you to be able to simplify it so others can help solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
a = []
g = lambda x,y: list(range(x,x+y))
a.append(g(7,4))
a.append(g(11,4))
```

**a:**

```
[[7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14]]
```

---

If I understand properly your condition `n` consecutive rows where the value is increasing `(x1<x2<x3<x4)`

This solution will help:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65090526/6660373
```

You need to modify as per your requirement.

Borrowing the code from that answer:

```
# Is the current "Close" increasing or same (compared with previous row)
df['incr'] = df.Close >= df.Close.shift(fill_value=0)
# Generate the result column
df['DaysDecr'] = df.groupby(df.incr.cumsum()).apply(
    lambda grp: (~grp.incr).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
df.drop(columns='incr', inplace=True)
```

---

```
N=3
idx = df.loc[(df['DaysDecr'].rolling(window=N , min_periods=N)\
                          .apply(lambda x: (x==0).all()).eq(1))].index
f = lambda x: list(range(x-N+1,x+1))
for i in idx:
    print(f(i)) # <--------- here is your indices where the condition is satisfied
```

---

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

---

**df:**

```
    Date        Close       incr    DaysDecr
0   2015-11-27  105.449997  True    0
1   2015-11-30  106.239998  True    0
2   2015-12-01  107.120003  True    0
3   2015-12-02  106.070000  False   1
4   2015-12-03  104.379997  False   2
5   2020-11-18  271.970001  True    0
6   2020-11-19  272.940002  True    0
7   2020-11-20  269.700012  False   1
8   2020-11-23  268.429993  False   2
9   2020-11-24  276.920013  True    0
```

Comment: Awesome, this is it! Thank you very much :D

Comment: @helloworldnoob: Don't iterate the dataframe (For loop) just do like this. If I understand the problem then you want to have indices which satisfy that condition I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I will try that, thanks again. Do have a problem now from the lambda function since in the use case of visualising the data with mplfinance.plot , where the lambda function now outputs [[numbers],[numbers]] (a list of lists?)

But it looks like the other code in your example will fix this

Comment: you can flatten the list also. But I don't know the requirement so gave you the solution which you can modify as per your need.

Comment: Brilliant, appreciate it a lot :)